# Can't see USGS WMS layers in ipyleaflet (leaflet.js for python)

Tags: python, leaflet, wms, ipyleaflet

Trying to use ipyleaflet (leaflet.js for python/jupyter widgets) to view a WMS layer representing 1m DEM availability. Source is the USGS National Map. End goal is to make a tool where I can draw a bounding box, download and process DEM data. Need the overlay to see where the 1m quality data is.

The WMS info I'm trying to use works fine with other services (e.g. QGIS and owslib), but with ipyleaflet I can't get it to show up, all I see is the basemap. I also tried some other National Map WMS services like elevation and hydrology, they had the same issue. Anybody have any ideas why this would be the case or how to fix it? Alternatively, any tips for other approaches to interactively draw a bounding box on a map?

Here's the script for the map viewer, not much to it...

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, basemap_to_tiles, WMSLayer

m = Map(basemap=basemaps.Stamen.Terrain,center=(39, -110), zoom=5)

wms = WMSLayer(
    url='https://index.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/3DEPElevationIndex/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS',
    layers='13',
    styles='default',
    opacity=0.4,
    format='image/png',
    transparent=True,
)

m.add_layer(wms)

display(m)
```

Comment: Any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Hi @IvanSanchez, nope, no console errors or warnings when running this script. Thanks!